# bundleAtPath gives me the wrong path

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ios5, filesystems

I've put a actual folder inside my app project and i would like to get the content of the folder out. I've tried the code below, but it always sends me to my home directory on my computer. How do you get to root level in your app?

```
NSArray *test = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/test"] bundlePath] error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", test);
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is your intent to have a subdirectory `tests` in your application's main bundle?  Or do you really want to have a separate bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle of your app is given by `[NSBundle mainBundle]`. Following your code example the path to your directory is:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test"]
```

Comment: Will i be able to put files into this folder, once i have created my app? I ask, because i've heard you can not put files into the main bundle once the app is complied?

Comment: Apps should not normally alter their bundles; its not *impossible* and may cause problems. If you need a folder which you add to later but is  "hidden" from the user create a folder for your app under "Application Support" - this must be named after your app or its bundle ID - and inside that create your folder. You can ship your app with the initial contents for this folder stored in your bundle and copy them into your application support folder on first run.

Comment: I need a folder, where i initially put some content in and where i can add content to once the app have been installed?

Comment: That is what the Application Support folder will do for you (a) when your app runs it should check for "<Application Support folder>/<app name or bundle ID>/test" and if it does not exist create it and copy its initial contents from, say, "<App Bundle>/Contents/Resources/test" (b) as needed the app can store new files into "<Application Support folder>/<app name or bundle ID>/test"

Comment: That would probably be smarter. How do i reference that folder though?

Comment: The function call `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)` will return you the path of the application directory (as the only element in an array). You can use `[NSBubdle mainBundle]` to get the bundle for your app and from that extrat your bundleID or application name. Combine these two and you have the path to your applications folder inside the Application Support directory. You will need to create this folder if it doesn't exist. Then within that folder create your "test" folder, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
```

and then set the appropriate subdirectory, e.g.

```
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"directory"];
```